# Откуда появляется отступ снизу в IE?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! При просмотре [страницы](http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/404.html) через IE на экранах 979px и меньше наблюдается такая ситуация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за отступ, и откуда он берется я понять не могу. Вероятно по той же причине небольшой отступ есть и в FF:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен если поможете разобраться с данным вопросом. Ссылка на страницу [здесь](http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/404.html).

Comment: У меня в фаерфоксе все нормально отображается. Какая версия ИЕ?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Пожалуйста, размещайте код непосредственно в вопросе. Ссылка на сайт не годится, потому что там через некоторое время код поменяется и вопрос потеряет смысл для будущих читателей.

Answer (score 1):

Если удалить боковые элементы из вашего `.header-top`, то все отступы пропадают. Конкретно в firefox небольшой отступ создается из-за иконки гамбургера слева. В ie отступ пропадает после удаления блока со скайпами итд.

Где-то вы плохо шапочку сверстали. Прогоните страницу в валидаторе.